# Make a new android native component with all options(props) of TouchableOpacity

Tags: android, react-native

I want to make a android native component with new feature in java and that can accept all props that TouchableOpacity have. we can say a new component based on TouchableOpacity that will inherit all its props.
is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Either you want to take advantage of a UI feature (e.g: update Android made for a specific widget), in this case I would say you can create your own library which would be a copy of TouchableOpacity, in addition to native changes you want to achieve.

On the other hand, if the changes you want to achieve are of Native non-UI API (like Toast API), you can create NativeModule that does that and export it and keep using TouchableOpacity as is.

Comment: thanx @Ahmed Mahmoud for the answer but I think I need something more to follow and then implement, I wish to inherit all the props of TouchableOpacity in the new native component.
let's say I want to make a button on native side when clicked show Toast like `<ToastButton message="show some toast"  {... inherit all TouchableOpacity Props}>{children} </ToastButton>`

by implementing like this I don't have to import Toast and touchableOpacity separately on RN side.